# Hibernate Query Association with Criteria: 'and' on children?

Tags: hibernate, collections, hibernate-criteria

Let's say I have a parent class Book, each with a list of Authors.
I am trying to find all the books with at least two Authors one named "Bob" and another one named "Alan".

Here is my Groovy code that doesn't work, it looks for books with an author named "Bob" and "Alan" at the same time, so it returns 0 items. I tried to create 2 aliases to create 2 joins, but Hibernate refuses to create 2 aliases to the same collection.

def crit = hsession.createCriteria(Book.class).createCriteria("authors").add(Restrictions.eq("name", "Bob")).add(Restrictions.eq("name", "Alan"))

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LogicalExpression like this

```
def crit = hsession.createCriteria(Book.class)
.createAlias("authors", "author")
.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("author.name", "Bob"), Restrictions.eq("author.name", "Alan")))
```

Comment: Thanks but that would return Books with either an author named Bob or an author named Alan, not the desired result of all the books with at least both authors Bob AND Alan.